# How can I override commit on my $dbh for testing?

Tags: perl, testing, dbi

I'm trying to modify my test so that any database work is rolled back at completion.  However, it seems that somewhere in the code I'm testing $dbh->commit is being explicitly called.  Is there a way to override the commit method of a DBI::db object to turn of commits entirely?

I've tried using Test::MockObject::Extends, but that seems to cripple the $dbh:

```
    $dbh = ConnectToDB();
    $dbh = Test::MockObject::Extends->new( $dbh );
    $dbh->mock( 'commit', sub { warn("Caught you committing.") } );
```

Later on when I try to use the $dbh to do some work, I get:

> Can't locate object method "fetchrow_array" via package "T::MO::::st"

Looks like the $sth's I ended up creating with the mocked $dbh aren't set up correctly.  Does anybody have a good method for turning commits off completely for a particular $dbh?

The database I'm connecting to is Oracle, for what it's worth.

**Update**

As it turns out, we were overriding &DBI::db::commit in a method very similar to Axeman's answer, but the commit was actually happening due to a rogue commit in a stored procedure that was being called during the run of my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this Q&D idea:

```
{
    my %old_commit;
    sub toggle_commit { 
        my $dbh   = shift;
        my $class = blessed( $dbh );
        if ( my $old_commit = $old_commit{ $class } ) {
            my $symb 
                = do { no strict 'refs'; 
                       \*{ "$class\::commit" };
                };

            *$symb = undef;
            unless ( $class->can( 'commit' )) { 
               *{ $symb } = $old_commit;
            }
            delete $old_commit{ $class };
        }
        else {
            $old_commit{ $class } = $class->can( 'commit' );
            {   no strict 'refs'; 
                *{ "$class\::commit" } = sub { say "Committed!" };
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Yes, this is a fair degree of Perl black magic.

*You* will have to sanity test it. Since this should only be used when *testing*, you should be able to partition the code so there is no chance of messing around like this in any *running* code.

Comment: This is very close to what we're actually doing.  We have this line in our test module which is only use'd as part of test scripts:  *DBI::db::commit = \&_no_commit;

Comment: sub no_commit { confess("Can't commit in a test script") }

Comment: @Ryan Olson, probably a neater idea would use my Adaptable mixin (not on CPAN) which reblesses a reference into a synthetic package used to push behavior onto the object. That package inherits from the existing class and can be rolled back into its original class.

Comment: Do you have that out on github or anything?  I'd certainly like to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests shouldn't really be talking to a real database at all.  One common approach is to swap out the database driver with a fake one using [DBD::Mock](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3aMock), [DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3aCSV) or [SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQLite), which lets you use isolated test data customized to each test suite, that can be wiped after each run and/or saved for analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [the Callbacks attribute](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#Callbacks) to intercept and ignore the commit() method call.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to turn off [AutoCommit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#AutoCommit) when you connect.

Comment: Sorry, should have shown the contents of ConnectToDb, but AutoCommit is off on this $dbh.